# SQL Server 2012 audit report on database user login name

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, report, audit

Trying to write an audit report for user permissions and access on a SQL Server 2012 database.

Using the following tables -

1. sys.database_role_members
2. sys.database_principals
3. sys.login_token
4. sys.database_permissions
5. sys.columns
6. sys.objects

Can get all the information required, **except** for the **Login name** associated with the database User.

Can anyone point me in the direction of where this information can be found?

Comment: Interesting, the user name and login ALWAYS match in my environments. When you create a db user you create it for a login. Users are mapped to logins. (There are rare exceptions though)

Comment: The dbo user on the database is mapped to an individual's login and should not have been, so without having to go through and check the properties of every user on every database I'd like to be able to pull through the Login name in the report. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Select **ORIGINAL_LOGIN()** as [Login]

The detailed info can be found here :
[Microsoft ORIGINAL_LOGIN()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/original-login-transact-sql)

To add to your comment:

You can either restrict the user from accessing the database or not.
Same is applied to the server

SQL server does not provide you with the features to "*Allow him/her to access the database, but if he/she does let me know*"

In that case you would need to provide some custom functionality such as creating a job that executes the query :

```
select login_time,original_login_name,DB_NAME(database_id) from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where original_security_id <> 0x01
```

And depending on condition etc (User1 logged on DB1 at xx:xx:xx time) insert into table.

You should also take a look at Logon Triggers which could prevent users from logging under a certain conditions and then recording it [Microsoft Logon Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers) if that is something you might want to consider

Comment: You were right, i was just in a hurry. My apologies

Comment: That just returns my login. I need to report the logins associated with the database users, so that I can highlight users that have access they shouldn't have.

Comment: Useful, but as the Login doesn't appear to exist anymore is there a way to identify database Users that are mapped to Logins that no loner exist as well?

Comment: What  version of sql server, and what kind of users are we talking about?

Comment: SQL Server 2012. Got an odd instance of a database User mapped to a Login that no longer exists on the server. Trying to highlight if this has happened anywhere else. Struggling to return information as Login doesn't exist to return. Bit of a confusing matter.

Comment: Check this https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/89929/problem-in-detecting-orphaned-user-on-database.html